# PHP Convert variable names to lowercase?

Tags: php

I have an api listener script which takes in get parameters. But I seem to be having issues when users tend to pass mixed case variable names on the parameters.

For example:

```
http://mylistenerurl.com?paramName1=Hello&paramname2=World
```

I need my listener to be flixible in such a way that the variable names will be interpreted case-insensitively or rather still all in lower case like after I process the query string on some function, they are all returned as lower-cased variables:

```
extract(someFunction($_GET));
process($paramname1, $paramname2);
```

Can anybody shed some light on this?

*much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$array_of_lower_case_strings = array_map( "strtolower", array( "This Will Be ALL lowercase.", ... ) );
```

So in your case:

```
$get_with_lowercase_keys = array_combine(
    array_map( "strtolower", array_keys( $_GET ) ),
    array_values( $_GET )
);
```

One thing I'll mention is you should be **VERY** careful with `extract` as it could be exploited to allow unexpected variables to be injected into your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Apply to your global variables ($_GET, $_POST) when necessary:

e.g. `setLowerCaseVars($_GET);` in your case

```
function setLowerCaseVars(&$global_var) {
    foreach ($global_var as $key => &$value) {
        if (!isset($global_var[strtolower($key)])) {
            $global_var[strtolower($key)] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

*Edit:* Note that I prefer this to using array_combine because it will not overwrite cases where the lower-case variable is already set.

Comment: One of the values has to be "overwritten", you just chose to remove everyone after the first, instead of everyone before the last. PHP's $_GET defaults to "last one stands". For example ?test=1&test=2 $_GET["test"] === 2.

Comment: That's true; this function should preserve it only in the case of `?test=1&TEST=1`; nevertheless, I haven't tested it, so I'm not certain of the behaviour in this case.

Comment: `&$value` is needless if you are going to be declaring directly to `$global_var[strtolower($key)]`.  The modified array will still contain all of the non-lowercase keys in addition to the newly pushed elements with lowercase keys.  In other words, this is going to bloat the array with redundant data.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has had a native function ([array_change_key_case()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php)) for this task since version 4.2 to change the case of first level keys.  To be perfectly explicit -- this function can be used to convert first level key to uppercase or lower case BUT this is not a recursive function so deeper keys will not be effected.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iMqJY))

```
parse_str('paramName1=Hello&paramname2=World&fOo[bAR][BanG]=boom', $_GET);

var_export($_GET);

echo "\n---\n";
$lower = array_change_key_case($_GET);

var_export($lower);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'paramName1' => 'Hello',
  'paramname2' => 'World',
  'fOo' => 
  array (
    'bAR' => 
    array (
      'BanG' => 'boom',
    ),
  ),
)
---
array (
  'paramname1' => 'Hello',        # N changed to n
  'paramname2' => 'World',
  'foo' =>                        # O changed to o
  array (
    'bAR' =>                      # AR not changed because not a first level key
    array (
      'BanG' => 'boom',           # B and G not changed because not a first level key
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Additionally, before calling `extract()` on user supplied data, you need to filter the keys against a whitelist of safe keys -- I recommend `array_intersect_key()`.